# ¿Como poner border shadow a una imagen cuando le clickas?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estoy haciendo un formulario para seleccionar el tipo de tarjeta a la hora de pagar y quiero que cuando seleccionen la imagen del tipo de tarjeta se le marque con un sombreado alrededor.

mi template es:

```
<form>
...
    <div class='formulario-tarjeta' class='row'>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="VISA" id="id_tipo_0" required="" type="radio" alt="Visa"><label for="id_tipo_0"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/visa.png' %}" alt="Visa"></label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="VISA_DEBIT" id="id_tipo_1" required="" type="radio"><label for="id_tipo_1"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/visa-electron.png' %}" alt="Visa Electrón"></label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="DINERS" id="id_tipo_2" required="" type="radio"><label for="id_tipo_2"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/dinners-club.png' %}" alt="Dinner Club"></label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="AMEX" id="id_tipo_3" required="" type="radio"><label for="id_tipo_3"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/amex.png' %}" alt="American Express"></label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="CODENSA" id="id_tipo_4" required="" type="radio"><label for="id_tipo_4"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/codensa.png' %}" alt="Codensa"></label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta"><input name="tipo" value="MASTERCARD" id="id_tipo_5" required="" type="radio"><label for="id_tipo_5"><img src="{% static '/img/tarjetas/mastercard.png' %}" alt="MasterCard"></label></div>
            </div>
...
</form>
```

y este mi css:

```
/*--- Formulario Compra ---*/
.formulario-tarjeta .opcion-tarjeta input[type='radio']{
    display: none;
}

.formulario-tarjeta .opcion-tarjeta label > img{
    border-radius: 5.6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(5,171,168,1);
}
```

la segunda clase del CSS es son los atributos que quiero añadirle a la imagen una vez esté seleccionada

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el tipo de `input` para que, en vez de tipo `radio`, sea de tipo `checkbox`.

De esta manera, puedes asociar una `label` a dicho checkbox tal y como lo estabas haciendo mediante el atributo `for` y, mediante el selector `+` (elementos adyacentes), hacer referencia a la label adyacente y, por consiguiente, a la imagen que esta tiene dentro.

Por último, solamente tendrás que comprobar si el input está checkeado mediante el selector `:checked`. Utilizo el selector de atributo `^=` que significa que busque todos los `input` que tengan un id que empiece por `id_tipo_`.

Tu ejemplo modificado (lo he simplificado un poco para que se viera el efecto sin tanto código):

```css
/*--- Formulario Compra ---*/
.formulario-tarjeta .opcion-tarjeta input[type='checkbox']{
    display: none;
}

.formulario-tarjeta .opcion-tarjeta label > img{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5.6px;
}

input[id^="id_tipo_"]:checked + label > img{   
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(5,171,168,1);
}
```

```html
<div class='formulario-tarjeta row'>
   <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta">
       <input name="tipo" value="VISA" id="id_tipo_0" required="" type="checkbox" alt="Visa">
       <label for="id_tipo_0">
          <img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com.es/medio/2015/12/21/bf63ef82rio_narcea_tineo_720x480.jpg" alt="Visa">
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2 opcion-tarjeta">
       <input name="tipo" value="VISA" id="id_tipo_1" required="" type="checkbox" alt="Visa">
       <label for="id_tipo_1">
          <img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com.es/medio/2015/12/21/bf63ef82rio_narcea_tineo_720x480.jpg" alt="Visa">
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Necesito que sea del tipo radio porque según el tipo de tarjeta aparece  un formulario u otro y no puede seleccionar 2 tipos de tarjetas al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @FDelgado Pero aquí cada checkbox va a ir asociado a su tarjeta, por lo que podrás mostrar un formulario u otro de la misma manera, simplemente comprobando si el checkbox está chequeado o no.

Comment: Tienes razón, puedo cambiarlo a checkbox sin problema, gracias.